# Porque al hacer click en el datalist no se refleja en el textarea

Tags: javascript, html5, entrada

La función consiste en que lo que yo se selecione en el datalist lo pase al textarea pero no se que pasa he buscado pero no entiendo.

```js
var control = 0;

function muestraentextarea(correo) {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById("envia_emails");
  cantidad_emails = txtarea.value.split(",");

  if (cantidad_emails.length <= 6) {
    if (control == 0) {
      txtarea.value += correo;
    } else if (control <= 6) {
      txtarea.value += "," + correo;
    }
  }

  control += 1;
  //alert(cantidad_emails.length);
}

var total = 0;
var valor_max = 0;

function valcantidad(txtarea) {
  cantidad_emails = txtarea.value.split(",");
  total = txtarea.value.length;
  if (cantidad_emails.length <= 8) {
    valor_max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cantidad_emails.length; i++) {
      valor_max += cantidad_emails[i].length;
    }

    if (total > parseInt(valor_max + 3)) {
      txtarea.value = txtarea.value.substring(0, parseInt(valor_max + 3));
    }
  } else {
    txtarea.value = txtarea.value.substring(0, total - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input list="browsers" name="correos" onchange="muestraentextarea(this.options[this.inputIndex].value)">
<datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>


<textarea name="envia_emails" id="envia_emails" style="width: 500px;" rows="5" onkeyup="valcantidad(this);"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hola, corrígeme si me equivoco ya que no se si te entiendo bien, lo que quieres es que lo que yo seleccione en el datalist , se agrega de manera automatica al textarea , basandome en tu código, si yo selecciono <option value="Internet Explorer">, entonces Internet Explorer, se agrega a tu textarea, es eso?

Comment: si exacto @Andrés

Comment: El problema es aqui `<input list="browsers" name="correos" onchange="muestraentextarea(this.options[this.inputIndex].value)">`.  
`this.inputIndex` no esta definido. Por lo que no puede coger `value` de `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

La parte donde intentas obtener el valor que se ha seleccionado es la que esta mal.

Esta parte

```
onchange="muestraentextarea(this.options[this.inputIndex].value)"
```

Debe ser cambiada por

```
onchange="muestraentextarea(this.value)"
```

Eso te permitirá obtener el valor correctamente, y no tienes que pasarte a Jquery o cambiar tu código drásticamente ;)

Comment: si funciono gracias @Kenny

Comment: Si te ha funcionado puedes marcar mi respuesta como aceptada. Ha sido un gusto ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: tengo una pregunta el lo pasa pero dando enter con onkeypress funcionara para que cuando seleccione cualquier opcion lo pase automaticamente?

Comment: Sin importar el evento, this.value tiene el valor del input al momento del evento. Así que tienes que verificar que tecla se esta presionando para que solo se ejecute tu codigo con una tecla en especifico, pero si funcionara.

Answer (score 1):

Sin usar jquery podria quedar asi

```html
<input list="browsers" id="myId" name="correos" onchange="handler()">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
<textarea name="envia_emails" id="envia_emails" style="width: 500px;" rows="5" ></textarea>

<script>
 var control = 0;

 function handler() {
     var correo = document.getElementById("myId").value;
     var txtarea = document.getElementById("envia_emails");
     cantidad_emails = txtarea.value.split(",");

     if (cantidad_emails.length <= 6) {
         if (control == 0) {
             txtarea.value += correo;
         } else if (control <= 6) {
             txtarea.value += "," + correo;
         }
     }

     control += 1;
 }

</script>
```

De esta forma cada vez que cambie el `input` sera anadido su valor al `textarea`.
El problema lo tenias al manejar el evento `onchange` del input. Para solucionarte esto seleccione los elementos por su `id` y asi usar su valor

Comment: Pienso que el OP esta preguntando que esta mal con su codigo, porque menciona "no se que pasa". Modificar lo que el ya tiene plantea una situación completamente diferente. Aun cuando soluciona su problema (que esta bien) no responde en la mejor forma su pregunta (que no esta tan bien). Por eso he votado negativa tu respuesta.